# Scan and Check for Binary Numbers

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, binary, binary-data

I managed to complete the assignment, but then I realized one fatal flaw: I didn't enable the code to accept a string of binary numbers. I managed to get the code to loop like I wanted until a binary number (either a 0 or 1) was entered, but I can't figure out how to enable the code to accept a string of binary numbers (ie: 1010) without ruining the loop I've created.

I'll also include the instructions as well: *1) Request an individual to enter a binary number and 2) Manage to test the input for compliance with the binary number system (only 0 and 1 are allowed).*

```
      boolean b = false;

        System.out.println("\nEnter a binary number:");
        do {
            Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int binaryNumber = scan1.nextInt();

            if (binaryNumber > 1 || binaryNumber < 0) {
                System.out.println("\nInvalid input. Try again.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("\nThe binary number \"" + binaryNumber + "\" is valid.");
                break;
            }
        } while (!b);
```

How would I go about editing the code to include a string of binary numbers, but still maintain the loop and other details above? Or will I have to completely change the code in order to include and accept the binary string?

Comment: 1. `Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);` should be before the loop (though not required). 2. `if (binaryNumber > 1 || binaryNumber < 0` is missing a closing `)`. 3. You need to check each digit of the user input. This might be easier reading a `String`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp 1. I'll be sure to change it. 2. In the original code, I had the closing " ) " but edited out the comments, so I accidentally removed them. 3. I'll try to revamp the code using a string. I tried earlier, but my conditional "if" statement comes back with incorrect syntax. If I change "binaryNumber" to a string instead, my computation doesn't compute and I get errors. Do you have any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't declare a scanner object in your loop. for every iteration of your loop you are instantiating another Scanner object. Declare and initialize it above and outside the loop.

Accept the input as a string then validate the fact that what was supplied is indeed a binary number:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

String binaryNumber = "";
while (binaryNumber.equals("")) {
    System.out.print("Enter a Binary Number: --> ");
    binaryNumber = scanner.nextLine();
    if (!binaryNumber.matches("[01]{1,}"))  {
        System.err.println("Invalid Binary Number Entered! Try Again...");
        binaryNumber = "";
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("The binary number \"" + binaryNumber + "\" is valid.");
    }
}
```

The **if** statement's condition (`!binaryNumber.matches("[01]+")`) make use of the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method along with a small [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (RegEx) to ensure (validate) a string representation of a binary value was supplied. If not then the User is informed and allowed to try again.

The regular expression used (`"[01]{1,}"`) basically means: *it's a match if the string supplied **does** contain one or more of just 0's and 1's.*

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I'm really glad you added more commentary as well, that way I can recognize what I've done wrong and learn from my mistakes. So, thank you for helping me solve the issue, but also thank you for giving a thorough explanation for why the answer is correct and how to avoid the issues in the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the binary using REGEX `[01]+` which means any combination from 0 and 1 repeated one or more.
if there is no match then continue until to find s valid binary and exit the loop.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nEnter a binary number:");
        do {
            String binaryNumber = scanner.nextLine();
            if (!binaryNumber.matches("[01]+")) {
                System.err.println("Invalid Binary Number Entered! Try Again...");
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("\nThe binary number \"" + binaryNumber + "\" is valid.");
            break;
        } while (true);
        scanner.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! All I have to do now is go through and edit the code more so that it excludes 0 as a starting number. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of turning the input into an int, you can have the input as a String and match it with a regex, such as `^[0-1]+$`

Putting that into code, it would be

```
boolean b = false;

System.out.println("\nEnter a binary number:");
do
{
  Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
  String binaryNumber = scan1.next();

  if (!binaryNumber.matches("^[0-1]+$"))
  {
    System.out.println("\nInvalid input. Try again.");
  }
  else
  {
    System.out.println("\nThe binary number \"" + binaryNumber + "\" is valid.");
    break;
  }
} while (!b);
}
```

Comment: For this code, I entered the "if (binaryNumber.matches(`^[0-1]+$`))" and received two different errors. One stated that there were illegal characters, and the other stated "else without if." Thank you for the feedback, though, I appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to check the code before I posted the answer. The binaryNumber variable is supposed to be a String, not an int. The answers are also swapped, so it should instead be `if (!binaryNumber.matches(regex))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() function to do this.
`

```
    System.out.println("\nEnter a binary number:");
    do
    {
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String binaryNumber = scan1.nextLine();
        String str[] = binaryNumber.split("[01]{1,}");
        if (str.length > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nInvalid input. Try again.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("\nThe binary number \"" + binaryNumber + "\" is valid.");
            break;
        }
    } while (!b);`
```

I think this helps